# Why can't I display Date anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'd like to simply display the current year on a span, I tried yesterday on my dev side site, it wokrs directly. When I tried to do it again (because it wasnt saved ..) I just can't do it anymore and I can't figure what I'm doing differently from yesterday. Please help

```js
const currentYear = document.getElementById('currentYear')

function showYear() {
    currentYear.write(new Date().getFullYear());
}
showYear();
```

```html
<p>© <span id=currentYear></span> DevWeb</p>
```

Comment: Elements don't have a `write` method.

Comment: There's an error on the browser's development console telling you what the problem is.  Always check for errors first.

Comment: I swear I'm seeing myslef typing the .getElementById for remplacing the "document".write.. And it works, did I smoke too much or I did something else that I can't remember ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```js
currentYear.textContent = new Date().getFullYear();
```

example in jsFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/p1et386y/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew this one. 
It works, but I'm still confused about my method, I swear I'm seeing myslef remplacing the "document" from document.write by a const called with getElementById.. Maybe I did something diffently but I really can't remember